# can any one please solve this problem in vs code when ever installed new extensions it will error like this

Tags: vscode-extensions

> [2022-07-15 21:05:31.947] [renderer1] [error] EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Users\kolla.vscode\extensions.2875e1b2-bbaa-430f-be79-ed6faf48f323': Extract: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Users\kolla.vscode\extensions.2875e1b2-bbaa-430f-be79-ed6faf48f323'
> at W.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/kolla/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code2/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:78:209070)
> at async W.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/kolla/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code2/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:78:206457)
> at async te.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/kolla/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code2/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:78:213396)
> at async te.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/kolla/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code2/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:78:214664)

Comment: Have you tried restarting vs code or your computer?

Comment: Run VS code as administration to install any extension, That error happen because you don't have permission as a normal user to write on this folder.